# Transformar vetores em uma Matriz

Tags: python, array, matriz

Tenho vários sinais, onde s1, s2 até sn, são vetores de tamanho n, gostaria de uni-los em uma matriz para fique da seguinte forma:

```
matriz = ( [s1]
           [s2]
           ...
           [sn] )
```

De forma que eu consiga acessar um elemento em qualquer ponto, por exemplo, [4][433], o valor da posição de linha 4 e coluna 433.

Tentei abordagens com **np.vstack()**, mas **np.vstack()** realmente faz o proposto? Ou viajei?

Comment: Será isto: https://ideone.com/ynwhzM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há mistério:

```
matrix = [ [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 ],
           [  6,  7,  8,  9, 10 ],
           [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ],
           [ 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ] ]

print( matrix[2][3] )
```

Alternativamente, você pode usar o método `append()`:

```
matrix = []

matrix.append( [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 ] )
matrix.append( [  6,  7,  8,  9, 10 ] )
matrix.append( [ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ] )
matrix.append( [ 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ] )

print( matrix[2][3] )
```

Comment: Obrigado pela a resposta e cordialidade.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine que você tenha vários vetores **DE MESMO COMPRIMENTO** - vetores que possuem os mesmos números de elementos - e deseja montar uma `"matriz"` com estes vetores. Neste caso, você pode utilizar o algoritmo exibido abaixo. Observe também que para montar o referido algoritmo, importei a biblioteca `numpy`, anteriormente instalada em minha `IDE`.

```
import numpy as np

while True:
    try:
        m = int(input('Desejas manipular quantos vetores? '))
        if m < 1:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Quantos elementos terão em cada vetor? '))
        if n < 1:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')

listaA = list()
for i in range(1, m + 1):
    vetor = list()
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                v = int(input(f'Digite o {j}º valor da {i}ª lista: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        vetor.append(v)
    listaA.append(vetor)

matriz = np.array(listaA)
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada foi:\n{matriz}\033[m')
```

Observe que quando executamos este algoritmo nos é exibida a seguinte mensagem: `Desejas manipular quantos vetores?`. Neste momento devemos digita a quantidade de vetores e pressionar enter. Em seguida, recebemos a segunda mensagem; `Quantos elementos terão em cada vetor?`. Neste momento devemos digitar a quantidade de elementos de cada vetor e pressionar enter.

A partir deste momento devemos inserir cada elemento de cada vetor e, em seguida, pressionar enter.

Uma vez tendo inserido todos os elementos de todos os vetores, o algoritmo montará uma lista de listas definida como `listaA`. Em seguida, a `listaA` é submetida ao método `array` da biblioteca `numpy`, produzindo dessa forma, um array tabular onde, cada linha corresponde a um vetor.

Posteriormente esta matriz será exibida na tela.